# Conditional avatar

Tags: avatar

I am using a plugin that allows users to upload profile graphics in place of avatars. The plugin is "[User Avatar](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-avatar)".

I am displaying user profile graphics with this code:

```
    echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('user_email'), $size = '60')
```

It works fine except I would like it to function so that, if a user does not have a user profile graphic, it defaults to display nothing. If I use the avatar Discussions settings to display "Blank" when there is no user avatar I still get text that is wrapped around where the graphics would be, creating an empty square where a user profile should otherwise be.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance for considering.

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I am using "User Avatar"
http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-avatar/installation/

Comment: Please make that an edit to your question (and use the WYSIWYG formatting).

Comment: Okay, made as an edit. I hope that was sufficient. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago I wrote a discussion over at this WordPress.org thread regarding this. Check it out: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-avatar-4?replies=5

Here is the code you'll need in the template you want your avatars:

```
   <?php
    $uploads = wp_upload_dir(); //WordPress upload path
    $uploads_url = ( $uploads['baseurl'] ); //full url of upload dir
    $uploads_dir = ( $uploads['basedir'] ); //full path of upload dir
    $user_id = $post->post_author; //id of author (if used in loop)
    $avatar_filename = user_avatar_avatar_exists($user_id ); //function from plugin

if (file_exists($uploads_dir.'/avatars/'.$user_id .'/'.$avatar_filename)) {
    echo ('<img src='.$uploads_dir.'/avatars/'.$user_id .'/'.$avatar_filename.' class="user-avatar"/>');
}
else {
    echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('user_email'), $size = '60');
} ?>
```

EDIT: To show nothing when the gravar is empty use this (source above thread):

```
   <?php
    $uploads = wp_upload_dir(); //WordPress upload path
    $uploads_url = ( $uploads['baseurl'] ); //full url of upload dir
    $uploads_dir = ( $uploads['basedir'] ); //full path of upload dir
    $user_id = $post->post_author; //id of author (if used in loop)
    $avatar_filename = user_avatar_avatar_exists($user_id ); //function from plugin

   $hash = md5(strtolower(trim($user->user_email)));
   $uri = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . $hash . '?d=404';
   $headers = @get_headers($uri);


if (((preg_match("|200|", $headers[0])) || (file_exists($uploads_dir.'/avatars/'.$user_id .'/'.$avatar_filename))) {

if (file_exists($uploads_dir.'/avatars/'.$user_id .'/'.$avatar_filename)) {
    echo ('<img src='.$uploads_dir.'/avatars/'.$user_id .'/'.$avatar_filename.' class="user-avatar"/>');
}
else {
    echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('user_email'), $size = '60');
} 

} ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! But I am having trouble getting to it to echo nothing ("") if the avatar username and file name do not exist. Should the above code do that or should I add an echo nothing statement somewhere? Thanks again!

Comment: The above code will not do that, it checks for the uploaded avatar then displays the gravatar (if they don't have a gravatar shows a mystery man) I have updated the code to use a suggesting in the linked thread.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the filter that will do the trick:

```
function ns_filter_avatar($avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt, $args) 
{
    $headers = @get_headers( $args['url'] );
    if( ! preg_match("|200|", $headers[0] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    return $avatar; 
}
add_filter('get_avatar','ns_filter_avatar', 10, 6);
```

To work you have to add value `404` as third argument `$default` to `get_avatar()`. Example:

```
get_avatar( $user_email, 45, '404' )
```